# How to insert a multiple table a query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

**customer**:

[image]

and

**employee**:

[image]

How to insert multiple table in one query?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO saleorder ('employeeId','customerId','totalAmount','saleDate') values('$employeeId','$customerId','$totalAmount','$saleDate')";

$sql="INSERT INTO customer ('customerCode','customerName','gender','email') values('$customerCode','$customerName','$gender','$email')";
```

_customerId of customer is auto_increment and saleorderId of saleorder is auto_increment.

If you can help, please explain the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate insert queries in transactional block to make your oparation atomic, faster and safer (avoid inconsistency).